# Mudar ponto por virgula em value de input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma página com vários inputs todos do tipo text e com nomes diferentes e IDs diferentes.

Em todos eles existem o valor numérico com ponto separando os decimais (10.00) e gostaria de mudar esse ponto por virgula (10,00) utilizando JQuery.

Assim, quando a página terminasse de ser carregada os valores dos inputs mudaria o ponto por virgula automaticamente.

Alguém saberia como escrever a função?

Desde já agradeço imensamente.

Comment: Olá. Pode explicar melhor? a formatação que você precisa é do tipo máscara? ou seja, para trocar no input, ou é depois de postar, para salvar ou apresentar o valor em outro lugar?

Comment: Para trocar mesmo. Na página é carregada com inputs e em seu value tem números que contem pontos (.) e quero que o jquery mude esses pontos por virgula (,)

Comment: Se queres mudar quando a página carrega parece-me que o melhor é fazer isso no lado do servidor... é uma opção?

Comment: infelizmente não. Foi minha primeira opção más como a página é dinâmica o objeto retornado do servidor (trabalho com python) não é suportado a utilização de um for para usar um replace

Comment: Ok... então e queres mudar só 1 vez ou sempre que fôr digitado um novo valor com ponto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se você deseja mudar de todos os elementos ao carregar a página você pode fazer o seguinte:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        var val = $(this).val().replace('.',',');
        $(this).val(val);
    });
});
```

```css
input{display:block;margin:5px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="10.00" />
<input type="text" value="20.00" />
<input type="text" value="30.00" />
<input type="text" value="40.00" />
<input type="text" value="50.00" />
<input type="text" value="60.00" />
<input type="text" value="70.00" />
<input type="text" value="80.00" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Sendo a necessidade mostrar os números no formato PT-br, ou seja, com pontos no separador decimal, isso dentro do próprio input o mais recomendável é usar um plugin jquery, sugiro os seguintes:

MaskedInput
http://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/

MaskMoney
http://plugins.jquery.com/maskMoney/

Os plugins ajudam bem pois apresenta em PT-br (ou outro formato) mas envia no formato original, o que evita ter que fazer outra conversão para salvar em um banco de dados ou fazer operações matemáticas, tanto em javascript quanto no server-side, após a postagem.

Comment: sim pareceu que é  bem funcional mesmo. más não há problemas em enviar como "," não apesar de ser gravado no banco de dados como ".". Realmente só preciso que mude na página quando ela for carregada.

Answer (score 0):

Usando JQuery podes usar o *replace* para fazer a substituição de um carácter ou até mesmo de um conjunto de caracteres numa *String*:

```js
function alteraPonto(valorInput){
    alert("Valor original: " + valorInput.val());
    alert("Valor com virgula: " + valorInput.val().replace(".", ","));
    $(valorInput).val(valorInput.val().replace(".", ","));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="idInput" onchange="alteraPonto($(this))"/>
<input type="text" id="idInput2" onchange="alteraPonto($(this))"/>
```

Comment: funciona, más procuro algo mais dinâmico pois cada campo possui um nome, classe e ID único.

Comment: @HenriqueCasagrandeB, resposta editada

Comment: @HenriqueCasagrandeB você tem a possibilidade de adicionar uma classe extra apenas para chamar uma única vez no jquery, ex.: `class="sua-class inputFloat"` (...) `$('.inputFloat').val($('.inputFloat').val().replace(".", ","))`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado Gê Bender.

Comment: @HenriqueCasagrandeB, se a resposta solucionou o teu problema podes marcar como correta

Answer (score 0):

Apresento-lhe so métodos toFixed() e replace() do Javascripty:

```
var num = 5.56789;
var num_com_2_casas = num.toFixed(2);

var res = num_com_2_casas.replace('.', ',');

// resultado 5,57
```