# Aceitar virgula no calculo do jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

O sistema não funciona quando digita número com virgula, por exemplo 2,14, 22,14 e etc... somente com ponto final 2.14, 22.14 e etc...
Abaixo a função que utilizo.
Como usar função com o número digitado com virgula, não apresentar o ERRO NaN e o resultado também aparecer com vírgula.
Seria possível restringir o uso de ponto no campo ou até mesmo emitir uma alerta se o usuário digitar "."? Muito obrigado.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.temp').change(function(){
        var total = 0;
        var notas = 0;
        $('.temp').each(function(){
            var nota = Number(this.value);
            if(nota === 0) return;
            total = total + nota;
            notas++;
        })
        var t = (total/notas).toFixed(2);
        $('#media_temperaturaE').val(t);
    });
})
```

Abaixo a tela de digitação dos números para realizar o calculo, com os dois exemplos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo, dá uma olhada neste post: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54691/mudar-ponto-por-virgula-em-value-de-input A solução é tu fazer um replace no código, para alterar a vírgula para um ponto.

Comment: Esse .replace('.', ','); resolve o resultado final da operação, mas ainda continuo tendo que colocar "." para o cálculo da minha função da média funcionar.
Quero uma solução na qual minha função funcione com os números com vírgula, por exemplo, 2,1 e o resultado não ocorra o ERRO NaN.

Comment: A questão é que eu não sei se o JavaScript aceita cálculo com vírgulas. Linguagens de programação geralmente dividem a parte inteira da fração utilizando pontos.

Comment: O erro NaN acontece porque o valor contido na variável é uma string "Not a Number".

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa para seu problema é transformar as ',' em '.' enquanto o usuário digita:

```js
            $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
                var val = $($(this)).val().replace(',','.');
                $($(this)).val(val);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

**UPDATE**
Veja a lógica acima realizando uma soma simples.

```js
            $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
                var val = $($(this)).val().replace(',','.');
                $($(this)).val(val);
                $('#result').val(Number($('input[name="number_01"]').val()) + Number($('input[name="number_02"]').val()));
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
          <label for="">Number 01: </label><br>
          <input type="text" name="number_01" id="number_01"><br>
          <label for="">Number 02: </label><br>
          <input type="text" name="number_02" id="number_02"><br><br>
          <label for="">Result: </label><br>
          <input type="text" name="result" id="result">
        </form>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Solução muito bacana também, porém, a função não funciona... quando converte para virgula já aparece o NaN no campo de total...


    `<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.temp').change(function(){
            var total = 0;
            var notas = 0;
            $('.temp').each(function(){
                var nota = Number(this.value);
                if(nota === 0) return;
                total = total + nota;
                notas++;
            })
            var t = (total/notas).toFixed(2);
            $('#media_temperaturaE').val(t);
        });
    })`

Comment: Consegue postar inclusive o HTML ?

Comment: Todas as linguagens tem como padrão o americano para inteiros e decimais, ou seja, você não vai conseguir fazer o cálculo se não trocar a vírgula pelo ponto.