# Substituir ponto por virgula em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite

no exemplo abaixo somam se os valores de 3 caixas de texto, e o resultado sai na quarta, como fazer este resultado aparecer com virgula e nao com ponto?

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function id( el ){
        return document.getElementById( el );
}
function getMoney( el ){
        var money = id( el ).value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
        return parseFloat( money );
}
function soma()
{
        var total = getMoney('campo1')+getMoney('campo2')+getMoney('campo3');
        id('campo4').value = 'R$ '+total/100;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="" method="">
                <input name="campo1" id="campo1" value="25,60" /><br />
                <input name="campo2" id="campo2" value="5,15" /><br />
                <input name="campo3" id="campo3" value="2,63" /><br />
                <input name="campo4" readonly="readonly" id="campo4" /><br />
                <input type="button" onclick="soma()" value="Soma de Valores" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Há [uma outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11018/como-representar-dinheiro-em-javascript) e suas excelentes respostas que referem como tratar dinheiro em JS, dá uma olhada lá. A resposta simples/minimalista à tua pergunta seria `id('campo4').value = 'R$ ' + (total/100).toString().replace('.', ',');`.

Comment: Vitor, acho que [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54712/20615) é mais simples para sua dúvida. Mas conselho ver a que o @Sergio marcou como duplicata, está muito mais completa.

Comment: legal, mas onde acho esta resposta?

Comment: @VitorMarquesLourenço eu dei-te a resposta no primeiro comentário. E se leres a outra pergunta e respostas vais saber responder ainda mais detalhadamente.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Com o [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) do JavaScript podes ter isso adaptado dependendo do locale:

```
22.33.toLocaleString(); /* depende do locale */
"22,33"
```

Ou então usar uma predefinida, por exemplo:

```
22.33.toLocaleString('EN');
"22.33"
22.33.toLocaleString('PT');
"22,33"
```